# Custom strict weak ordering

Tags: c++, dictionary

Background: I am writing an algorithm that stores a map of objects to an associated attribute that I would like to accumulate. This is a cascading assignment procedure which loads this attribute onto a network using a predefined path through the network. The path is defined as a build-forward path from an origin in the network to all points through out the network.

Question: To achieve this I use a map with a custom comparator

```
bool pathLinkComp(const PathLink* lhs, const PathLink* rhs) 
{
    return (lhs != rhs) && (lhs->cost < rhs->cost);
}
```

Then in my cascading method I use this in the following manner

```
PathLinkTripsMap myMap(pathLinkComp);
myMap[pathLinkOfInterest] = 100.0;
// populate other pathLinksOfInterest with initial values

while (myMap.size())
{
    // pop
    auto  firstIterator = myMap.end(); --firstIterator;
    PathLink* link  = firstIterator->first;
    double    trips = firstIterator->second;
    myMap.erase(firstIterator);

    // do something with the popped data

    // move the trips back onto the previous link (unless we are at the end of the path)
    PathLink* backLink = link->backLink;
    if (backLink) myMap[backLink] += trips;
}
```

The problem with this is that if I use a strict weak ordering then I end up with the situation where if two PathLink objects have the exact same cost then they effectively become the same object for indexing purposes. If, instead of <, I use <= I get the correct behaviour but this obviously doesn't give a strict weak ordering which is what the comparator of std::map is supposed to do... is this a big deal to force std::map to operate in such a fashion?

Alternately how can I structure my comparator to achieve both strict weak and to keep separate keys separate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the value of the pointers (it appears your map type is map<PathLink const*,double>, right?) to differentiate items with equal costs:

```
bool pathLinkComp(const PathLink* lhs, const PathLink* rhs) {
  return (lhs->cost < rhs->cost)
    or (lhs->cost == rhs->cost and std::less<PathLink const*>()(lhs, rhs));
}
```

Comment: language breakdown there... "If I use <= instead of <, then.... "... <= doesn't give strick-weak-ordering

Comment: This should (at least) be `(lhs->cost < rhs->cost) || ((lhs->cost == rhs->cost) && std::less<PathLink const*>()(lhs, rhs))`.

Comment: Any particular reason you're not writing `||` and `&&`?!

Comment: That's perfect, it explicitly shows the comparison I'm trying to make... I'm pretty sure it's functionally equivalent to my original function [lhs->cost >= rhs->cost && lhs != rhs] but in the opposite order. The difference is that it shows the ordering relationships a lot better

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Personal preference.

Comment: @Jamie: No, they aren't equivalent!  `(lhs != rhs)` isn't the logical inverse of `(lhs < rhs)`.

Comment: @Fred: Umm, but it's not valid C++!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Yes, it is.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Since before 1998; see §2.5p2 and §2.12p1 in the standard.

Comment: @Fred: It seems you are right!  Why did no-one tell me about this?!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need a `std::multimap`, which allows for non-unique keys.

Incidentally, I don't think there's any need for the `(lhs != rhs)` expression in your comparator.

Comment: I think you're right about the superfluous (lhs != rhs)... I think that was a left over from when I modified the comparator from >= (because I want the most costly link first - now I use end()-1, previously I used begin())